# Cypress index position to came before a specific string

Tags: position, cypress, each

I need to check a string on a Thead to come before a specific string.
User need to be before Primium  like in the e.g
[image: TH titles]

Here is the code I am using

```js
it('test', () => {
    cy.visit('url')

    cy.wait('@geturl')
      .its('response.statusCode')
      .should('be.oneOf', [200, 201])

    cy.url().should('include', 'url')
    cy.get('h1').should('contain', 'url List')

    cy.get('thead').find(`th:contains('User')`).invoke('index').as('userIndex')

    cy.get('thead')
      .find(`th:contains('Premium')`)
      .invoke('index')
      .as('premiumUndex')

    cy.get('@userIndex').then((userIndex) => {
      cy.get('@premiumUndex').then((premiumUndex) => {
        expect(userIndex).to.be.lessThan(premiumUndex)
      })
    })
  })
```

**It is working, but I need to check the User column is before Premium column and after Agent column** Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check three column headers using `.slice()` to get just the columns you want.

Then map elements to the text. Use `.trim()` if there is whitespace around it.

```js
cy.get('thead th')
  .invoke('slice', 4, 7)
  .then($th => [...$th].map(th => th.innerText.trim()))  
  .should('deep.eq', ['Agent', 'User', 'Premium'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can see is to take all the header texts as one long string and check that "AgentUserPremium" is in it.

In case there are whitespace characters like " " or "\n", add a filter to remove these.

```js
cy.get('thead th')
  .invoke('text')
  .then(text => text.replace(/\s/g, ''))
  .should('contain', 'AgentUserPremium')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking for headers as part of a test, the a stronger test would be to set the headers as a static variable within your test and then use `.each()` to check each header in the table.

```js
const headers = [
  "",
  "Number",
  "Code",
  "Client",
  "Agent",
  "User",
  "Premium",
  "Status",
  "Time",
  "",
];
cy.get("th")
  .should("have.length", headers.length)
  .each((header, index) => {
    expect(header).to.have.text(headers[index]);
  });
```

Here is a working [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/integration/tableHeaders.md) based on the screenshot.